# how laravel singleton pattern mange to reflect the changes on subsequent calls?

Tags: php, laravel, dependency-injection

As all we know the singleton concept is very useful for us. But some of the underlying concept makes me scratch my head.

say we bind one object as singleton in the following way.

```
$this->app->singleton(Singleton::class, function () {
            return new Singleton();
        });
```

now as we know the object will only be resolved once and then it will be saved in the container's instances class property and return in the following way

```
if (isset($this->instances[$abstract]) && ! $needsContextualBuild) {
            return $this->instances[$abstract];
        }
```

okay everything fine till now.now we are modifying the instance from a controller

```
function index(){
   $abc = app(Singleton::class);
   $abc->a = 'b;
}
```

and we are accessing the singleton on other function

```
function test(){
   echo app(Singleton::class)->a;
}
```

and of course we can see it prints 'b'. But actually what we are doing in index function is saving the singleton to a variable $abc and we are modifying that variable in which I suppose reside a copy of the singleton object from the container's singleton array since laravel just return a value from its container instances array with index matches to the class name.

but how laravel manage it to reflect the change on next function when we are resolving the singleton object as above change only affects the $abc variable.

I am sure the answer could make me laugh as I am sure I have missed something in my way of thinking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, object instances are [passed by reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php).

`app(Singleton::class)` does not create a copy, it always returns (a reference to) the one and only instance of `Singleton::class`.

Comment: `$a = ['d' => ['abc']];
$b = $a['d'];
$b[] = 'fff';
print_r($a);` as you can see here it just return a copy of the value and save in $b and doing changes does not modify the actual array is this the same way laravel return the singleton object too ?

Comment: No, this snippet does not manipulate *object instances*, these are scalar values. Scalar values are indeed passed by value (copy) (yeah this is confusing, some people hate PHP just for that)

Comment: @RandomSeed What could cause an issue with this? I have a property on a singleton which I modify and later access, and the modification is lost.